# Non-standard, structured CSV - regexing structures

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a CSV in following convention

```
val1,val2,outerStruct1{valA,valB,innerStruct2{valX, valY},valC},...
```

The problem is when I try to regex the outerStructure1 I get:

`outerStruct1{valA,valB,innerStruct2{valX, valY}`
instead:

`outerStruct1{valA,valB,innerStruct2{valX, valY},valC}`

So apparently it returns on the first `}` instead of last (valid) one. My current regex is:

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\{.*?\})`

How can I expand it to reach the appropriate right brace?

Comment: I'm using Java, but I think I can reformat regex from other langs to my purposes.

Comment: Is that `outerStruct1`, `innerStruct2` part's structure static or does it vary between records?

Comment: The stingy repetition operator `*?` specifically returns the shortest possible match.  Looks like you are looking for the greedy repetition operator `*` instead; but you should take care to not allow the match to cross a field boundary. Regex isn't really suitable for this, although it can be made to work, for a limited and hard-coded number of nesting levels.

Comment: @triplee, Greedy operator is indeed crossing to last curly bracket in the tested input ignoring structures between. Nesting is limited to 2 levels (meaning structure of structures of values, e.g: o{i1{1,2,3},i2{1,2,3}})

Comment: @aMoosingOne, Java regex engine doesn't support recursion so if I gave you one, it would have been useless to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\{.*?\}(?=(?:[^{}]*|\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\})*$)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/rC9vO9/4)

The general idea is to check that after your match, only balanced curly brackets remain til the end of the string.

However, note that this regex is not recursive and will not handle nesting greater than 2 levels.

Comment: In fact it works great for more that 2 levels! It matches correctly `val1,val2,o{valA,valB,i{valX, valY},valC,i{i2{i3{i4{i5{val}},val},val},val,val}},val3`

Comment: @aMoosingOne, what I meant by that that if is there is another value with nesting > 2 after that. In fact I had to update it a little because it was handling only 0 and 1 levels.